# tmux + emacs : ctrl is not reconized

Tags: emacs, tmux

I just installed tmux. But when I'm using emacs in the tmux environment, emacs doesn't recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as it should. Instead it is I believe recognize as Meta <kbd>CTRL</kbd> = M + [ ??)

Is there any special binding line to write in the config file of tmux ?